# A sufficient condition for $x^p-x-a$ to be primitive

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Let $p$ ba a prime number and $F_p$ be the finite field with $p$ elements. Characterize the set of $a\in F_p$ such that $f=x^p-x-a$ is a primitive polynomial i.e. $x$ generates the multiplicative group of $F_p[x]/(f)$.

Comment: Can only show irreducibility with e.g. Chebotarev. Primitivity remains a mistery.

Comment: The polynomial $x^p − x − a \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ is primitive if and only if $a$ is primitive in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Thanks! Can you write it as an answer with a reference, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further to my hint above, that

> The polynomial $x^p − x − a \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ is primitive if and only if $a$ is primitive in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

I found the result of Cao to be of use, I think, from $2010$

[On the Order of the Polynomial $x^p − x − a$](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/034.pdf)